# leafletDirectiveMarker disable focus when user click outside the map

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, cumulocity

I have a click function on the marker which will enable the marker popup. But when the user clicks outside the map I want to disable this focus. How to do this?

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.click', function (event, args) {

            $scope.markers['m' + args.model.value.id].focus = true;

            createTemplateForPopup(args.model.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply listen to a window event and disable all focus on click:

```
$window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  $scope.markers.forEach(function(marker) {
   marker.focus = false;
  });
});
```

You might prevent default to not trigger the window click when someone selects a marker:

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.click', function (event, args) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $scope.markers['m' + args.model.value.id].focus = true;
  createTemplateForPopup(args.model.value);
});
```

The only problem is that this will always trigger. So it is good practice to remove the EventListner when the map is destroyed.